# Apple Mail: Mailboxes with different IMAP path prefixes

Tags: mail.app, email, imap

For the Apple Mail client (this problem does not appear for Thunderbird Mail), I struggle with the following problem: I seem to have Mailboxes with different IMAP prefix paths. If the IMAP path prefix is empty, I see a bunch of Mailboxes (not under the label "Mailboxes", which has the default ones, like "Inbox", "Drafts", "Sent" and "Trash"). If I change this prefix to `INBOX`, I see a different set of Mailboxes (again, the standard Mailboxes ("Inbox", etc) are available here, too). I would like to have all Mailboxes show up at the same time (using a unified path prefix). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you chnage the prefix?

Comment: I change the prefix in the way it is e.g. described in the answer by @howdyturn.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the IMAP prefix can be set in Mail Preferences > Accounts > mail@example.com > Server Settings > Choose **Advanced IMAP settings**. Type in your "IMAP Path prefix" e.g. INBOX

[image: IMAP Path prefix macOS 10.12.x]

Note: In previous macOS versions (e.g. El Capitan, Yosemite) you will find "IMAP Path prefix" setting below the Mail Preferences > Accounts > mail@example.com >  **Advanced** tab instead.

[image: IMAP Path prefix macOS 10.10.x]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yet, it does not help with the goal to unify mailboxes that seem to exist under different IMAP Path Prefixes (The first question would be how they actually got under different IMAP Paths, which I don't know).

Comment: @osdf: Usually mixed IMAP path are caused by different mail clients. Maybe you have used multiple email in the past.